# js regex not matching word boundaries \b

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string

```
Vestibulum purus quam, \n\nscelerisque ut, \nmollis sed, nonummy id.
```

I'm trying to get this result

```
Vestibulum purus quam, \nscelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id.
```

That is to replace double `\n\n` with `\n` and single `\n` with `""`

I'm using this regex:

```
var regex = /\B\\n/g,
    result = string.replace(regex, " ");
```

which I tried in https://regex101.com/r/sV9eQ1/1 but it is not working at all even if the Regex should do the job.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzKqzm?editors=0001)

Any clue?

Comment: What are `\n` in your string? a newline or a literal backslash followed by a "n"? Could you show us how you declare your string?

Comment: They are supposed to be newline

Comment: In this case why do you escape `\n` in your pattern? and why you wrote `\n` in regex101?

Comment: Good question; if you try http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzKqzm?editors=0001 you will see that with `\B` it won't take newline

Comment: Beware that there are no word boundaries between two newlines (since a word boundary is between a character from `\w` and a character from `\W` or the limits of the string)

Comment: That was the problem, I found the solution, really thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks on Casimir comment and Tim007 clue, I solved it using:

```
/\n(?![\n]+)/g
```

because of the `newline` the `\B` won't work.

Thank you all.

Comment: Why did you put `\n` inside brackets? Are you afraid by the evil influence of the quantifier `+` (that has the well-known magical power to break an escape sequence in two separated literal characters)?

Comment: @casimir perhaps he thinks the newline committed a crime by breaking the anchor, but if truth is it's been framed.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach:

```
var str = "Vestibulum purus quam, \n\nscelerisque ut, \nmollis sed, nonummy id.";
var replaced = str.replace(/\s([\n]{1})/gi, " ").replace(/([\n]{2,})/gi, "\n");

console.log(replaced);
// the output:

Vestibulum purus quam,
scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(\\n[\\n]+)
```

Hope this helps.

```
string = 'Vestibulum purus quam, \n\n\n\nscelerisque ut, \nmollis sed, nonummy id.'

result = string.replace(/(\\n[\\n]+)/g, " ");
//console.log("Result:", string.indexOf("\n\n");
console.log("Result:", result);
```